# Facebook: How to request for instagram_basic permission during app review?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, facebook-app-requests, instagram-graph-api

How to request permission for instagram_basic during app review? I searched for the permission in the app review > current request dashboard but it seems not available

[image: Add Permissions and Features in App review]

Are there any other steps that needs to be complied? I think I am missing something out.
The App also finished the Business Verification.

Comment: Products -> Instagram -> Settings

Comment: @misorude Found it. Thank you!